# SQL SELECT SUM of columns is returning incorrect values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using an SQL select and a part of query is below

```
    SELECT coalesce(C2.PRE,0) as PRE,coalesce(C4.PREX,0) as PREX,
            coalesce(C2.AFTER,0) as AFTER,  coalesce(C4.AFTERX,0) as AFTERX
```

it returns 4 columns

```
    1   0   0   0
```

I tried to add 3 more columns to the SQL SELECT , and these 3 columns is to find some SUM values based on the above columns

```
    PRESUM =(PRE+PREX) = 1+0=1
    AFTERSUM =(AFTER+AFTERX) =0+0=0
    TOTAL =PRESUM+AFTERSUM)= 1+0=1

The new SQL is  

    SELECT coalesce(C2.PRE,0) as PRE, coalesce(C4.PREX,0) as PREX,
          coalesce(C2.AFTER,0) as AFTER,  coalesce(C4.AFTERX,0) as AFTERX,  
           coalesce((PRE+PREX),0) as PRESUM
           coalesce((AFTER+AFTERX),0) as AFTERSUM
           coalesce((PRESUM+AFTERSUM),0) as TOTAL
```

and result returning is

```
    1   0   0   0   0   0   0 ,
```

but the last 3 columns [PRESUM,AFTERSUM,TOTAL]  should return   1   0   0. Anything wrong in the way i calculated the sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing arithmetic, `NULL` results in a `NULL` value.  So, you probably want this:

```
SELECT coalesce(C2.PRE,0) as PRE,coalesce(C4.PREX,0) as PREX,
       coalesce(C2.AFTER,0) as AFTER, coalesce(C4.AFTERX,0) as AFTERX,
       ( coalesce(PRE, 0) + coalesce(PREX, 0) ) as PRESUM,
       ( coalesce(AFTER, 0) + coalesce(AFTERX, 0) ) as AFTERSUM,
       ( coalesce(PRESUM, 0) + coalesce(AFTERSUM, 0) ) as TOTAL
```